# How do I format lists that are continuously being appended and added to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, formatting, append

I have an empty list which is continuously being appended when data is inputted via the input function e.g.

`x = []`

After the first input, the list will be automatically appended to something like this:
`x = [CAR]`

how do I format the list to show something like this:

```
>>>Encryption 1: CAR
```

Then after the second input, the list will show :

`x = [CAR, SHIP]`

```
>>>Encryption 1: CAR
>>>Encryption 2: SHIP
```

I have started by creating two lists:
`x = []
encryption_labels = []` this is where i am planning the Encryption 1, Encryption 2... and so on. To be formed.

but i am stuck :(

Comment: What's the purpose of this formatting? If you just wish to print the list like that you can create a method that formats a string like that or do you need the values in the list to be prepended with "Encryption x:"

Comment: This isn’t very clear. Can you be more specific, both about the current question and your overarching goal or the context surrounding this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just one list, you can iterate through the list using `enumerate()` to get both the index and the value. Then you can print stuff out depending on that:

```
x = ['CAR', 'SHIP']

for idx, val in enumerate(x):
    print(f">>>Encryption {idx + 1}: {val}")
```

which prints the following:

```
>>>Encryption 1: CAR
>>>Encryption 2: SHIP
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through and access the respective index

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  print(encryption_labels[i] + ": " + x[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `x` to `encryption_labels` at the end after finishing appending all the elements to `x`:

```
encryption_labels = [f">>>Encryption {i+1}: {xi}" for i, xi in enumerate(x)]
```